# How to alter Column name in hibernate entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have the following hibernate entity:

```
@Table(name="tbl_template")
@Entity
@Audited
public class StatementTemplate {
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "template_name")
    private String templateName;
    ...
```

}

I changed the column name from template_name to stmt_name

```
@Column(name = "stmt_name")
private String templateName;
```

It turned out that the instead of changing the column name hibernate added another column named stmt_name, now I have template_name as well as stmt_name

I have following hibernate properties set up

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

How can I get the column altered from template_name to stmt_name?

Answer (score -1):

Stopping your app, running ALTER TABLE, and starting the app again?

Comment: Not too sure abt your question here, but I have restarted the app, but I do I need to alter the table using ALTER TABLE sql command? Won't it be done automatically?

Comment: yes, good old SQL :) I'm not sure about hibernate but would guess it doesn't track renames.